# What controls the number of partitions when reading Parquet files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, parquet

**My setup:**

Two Spark clusters. One on EC2 and one on Amazon EMR. Both with Spark 1.3.1.

The EMR cluster was installed with [emr-bootstrap-actions](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-bootstrap-actions/tree/master/spark). The EC2 cluster was installed with Spark's default EC2 scripts.

**The code:**

Read a folder containing 12 Parquet files and count the number of partitions

```
val logs = sqlContext.parquetFile(“s3n://mylogs/”)
logs.rdd.partitions.length
```

**Observations:**

- On EC2 this code gives me 12 partitions (one per file, makes sense).
- On EMR this code gives me 138 (!) partitions.

**Question:**

What controls the number of partitions when reading Parquet files?

I read the exact same folder on S3, with the exact same Spark release. This leads me to believe that there might be some configuration settings which control how partitioning happens. Does anyone have more info on this?

Insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It seems that the many partitions are created by EMR's S3 file system implementation (`com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem`).

When removing

```
<property><name>fs.s3n.impl</name><value>com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem</value></property>
```

from `core-site.xml` (hereby reverting to Hadoop's S3 filesystem), I end up with 12 partitions.

When running with `EmrFileSystem`, it seems that the number of partitions can be controlled with:

```
<property><name>fs.s3n.block.size</name><value>xxx</value></property>
```

Could there be a cleaner way of controlling the # of partitions when using `EmrFileSystem`?

Comment: If the data resides on HDFS within EMR, does it still give you the same higher number of partitions?

Comment: It seems like the many partitions come from the EMR S3 filesystem implementation (`com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem`). See my update. This makes me assume that reading from HDFS would return a 'normal' number of partitions, since that would use Hadoop's own fs implementation (haven't tested that though).

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, default block size is 64MB. Is this of concern?  More partitions allow for more parallelized tasks.  S3 does not behold to filesystem block structure and data is fetched from S3 by HTTP ranged gets anyway.  There may be a task overhead that may need to be balanced against block size.   One could adjust the block size with sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.block.size").

Comment: You're right Christopher. Thanks for the hadoopConfiguration trick, hadn't thought of that. I guess I'll have to live with approximating the amount of partitions with that. ERMFS weirdness :)