# Predetermining number of partitions of RDD

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark, hdfs

> 1)How to Pre-Determine the number of RDD partitions that will be
> created?
> 2)what all factors does partitioning of data depend on? Is
> it only the size of the data and way it is stored(compressed, sequence
> etc..)

For Simplicity, assume i have a 6GB file in HDFS stored as plain text file.

My cluster is a EC2 cluster with below config,

> 1 master node - m3.xlarge(4 cores, 15GB Ram)
>
> 4 core nodes - m3.xlarge(4 cores , 15GB Ram each)

**UPDATE:**
What happens if the same is stored in s3, HBase or any NoSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partitions is dependent on the file type. In your case, since it is an HDFS file, then the default number of partitions is the number of input splits and that will depend on your hadoop setup. But if all you want is a way of understanding how this works.

From [`HadoopRDD.getPartitions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala):

```
val inputSplits = inputFormat.getSplits(jobConf, minPartitions)
val array = new Array[Partition](inputSplits.size)
```

Comment: So if my HDFS block size is 128MB, then 6GB/128MB = 8*6 = 24 Splits, that means 24 partitions, it will be created, right?

Comment: What about s3? Any idea? Will it be same like HDFS?

Comment: your HDFS ans did clear my doubt atleast regarding HDFS. does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168280/spark-parquet-number-of-partitions has some answers regarding s3, if yes, is it correct?

Comment: If it is HDFS, then again it should be the same. Also, if you found this helpful, an upvote would be helpful :)

Comment: Basic idea is Spark does not try to solve how inbound data will be partitioned (unless its native method like sc.textFile). Spark just delegates to appropriate or user defined input formats to get split information. This idea is true for all kind of sources, be it S3, Oracle, Cassandra, HDFS and whatnot.